# Laravel Mass assignment fill() method skipping one value

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Problem: Assignment of **"role_id"**

**Code:**

```
function register(Request $request){
        $validated = $request->validateWithBag('ers', [
            'email'=>'required',
            'password'=>'required|min:6',
            'role_id'=>'integer',
            'name'=>'required',
        ]);

        $user = new User;
        $user->fill($validated);
        // $user->role_id = $request->role_id;
        $user->save();

        return response("Saved record");
    }
```

**What I have tried:**

1. renamed `role_id` to `roleid`
2. when I uncomment the manually `$user->role_id = $request->role_id` that works but I am wondering why isn't `fill()` doing that for me.

**Value's coming from:**

```
<select class="input100" name="role_id">
    <option value=1>Standard Customer</option>
    <option value=2>Doctor</option>
    <option value=3>Distributor</option>
</select>
```

Note that

- The database schema of users has role_id datatype integer (if this info is relevant)
- dd($request->all()) has role_id being passed
- dd($validated) also shows me role_id in array
- all 3 values except role_id is caught except role_id
- I get error that role_id isn't assigned value and the generated query below:

```
insert into
  `users` (
    `email`,
    `password`,
    `name`,
    `updated_at`,
    `created_at`
  )
values
  (
    abc@gmail.com,
    password123,
    Imran Ahmad,
    2022 -08 -17 05: 11: 34,
    2022 -08 -17 05: 11: 34
  )
```

Let me know if you want me to show you something further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fill()` is one of the mass assignment functions. In order to prevent mass-assignment vulnerability, in your model you should define which model attributes you want to make mass assignable. You may do this using the `$fillable` property on the model. Make sure `role_id` is in that list.

If you would like to make all of your attributes mass assignable, you may define your model's `$guarded` property as an empty array. If you choose to unguard your model, you should take **special care** to always hand-craft the arrays passed to Eloquent's `fill`, `create`, and `update` methods.

See more docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#mass-assignment).

Comment: Thank you very much! making $guarded empty worked.. wondering why no problem for other fields and it gets stuck on role_id.. 

also thank you for editing my post format, I am newbie so yea